# Emgu cv intermittent exception when creating image from bitmap

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, emgucv, system.drawing

I have a Windows forms application, based on .NET 4.6.1. I have included Emgu.cv from NuGet, version 4.1.0.3420.

Basically, the application points to a video file, using the VideoCapture object. I then query frames, one by one and process them. After processing, I query for the next frame.

The application runs on x64 and I have ensured that both my debug and release configurations are set to x64. The application runs fine in debug, never had an issue. However, in release, I have an intermittent issue where the application will break. Here is the thing, it is very intermittent. Sometimes it will break after just a few seconds of video, other times it could take minutes. And again, only in release it would seem, even though both are running x64.

Using `Trace.WriteLine` to track down the line that is breaking in release mode, I have found it to be this exact line that is causing the exception:

```
using (var cvImage = new Image<Bgr, byte>(bmOriginal))
```

As you can see, I am trying to simply create an OpenCv Image from a bitmap (bmOriginal is a System.Drawing.Bitmap that is passed in). As you can see, I have wrapped it in a using statement to help with memory management. Also, just before this line, I do make sure that the Bitmap passed in is not null before I try to create the OpenCv image. However, on this line, is where it get the very intermittent break. Here is the only error I get when it breaks:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll
>   Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

EDIT: I also wanted to note, in case it helps or some are wondering. When you call `QueryFrame`, it gives you a `Mat`. I then create a `Bitmap` from the `Mat` using the `Mat.Bitmap` property. This is because I do need to do some `System.Drawing` on the image. After that, I need the CV Image and that is when I call the line of code above that is failing. Keep in mind that I do make sure the bitmap is not null though.

I am pulling my hair out. Don't know how else to trace this and what might be causing it.

Thanks!

Comment: `cvImage` is in a `using` statement... but do you actually dispose `bmOriginal` eventually?

Comment: Well....I was disposing it at one point but since it is passed in as a argument/variable to the method that this using statement is inside of, I stopped disposing it because I figured GC would dispose it anyway after the using and when the method completes and the bitmap variable that was passed in goes out of scope. Is that true? What is the right thing to do?

Comment: `System.Drawing.Bitmap` is actually a wrapper around a GDI+ object. Because of that, they're not managed by the garbage collector, and need to be disposed manually.

Comment: While it is true that exact line is causing the problem, the problem lies within `bmOriginal`. The information above is not enough to point out the problem, need more information on how `bmOriginal` is created and stored. In my case, It cause the same error because I stored the image in a pictureBox but the error only spawn when it is accessed (creating the bitmap), by changing pictureBox to imageBox actually fix it.